# Could not build the application for the simulator

Tags: ios, xcode, flutter

I tried to run the flutter app on the IOS platform, it is showing an error and the error is not able to fix it.

It was working fine and I tried to add the firebase, from then I am getting this error.

output:

```
elamparithibalakrishnan@Elamparithis-MacBook-Pro ios % flutter run
Changing current working directory to: /Users/elamparithibalakrishnan/AndroidStudioProjects/quizi_mobile_app
Multiple devices found:
AOSP on IA Emulator (mobile) • emulator-5554                        • android-x86    • Android 9 (API 28) (emulator)
iPhone 12 Pro Max (mobile)   • 1E0E6387-F349-4ECA-9858-385698232158 • ios            • com.apple.CoreSimulator.SimRuntime.iOS-14-4 (simulator)
Chrome (web)                 • chrome                               • web-javascript • Google Chrome 89.0.4389.82
[1]: AOSP on IA Emulator (emulator-5554)
[2]: iPhone 12 Pro Max (1E0E6387-F349-4ECA-9858-385698232158)
[3]: Chrome (chrome)
Please choose one (To quit, press "q/Q"): 2
Running "flutter pub get" in quizi_mobile_app...                 1,214ms
Launching lib/main.dart on iPhone 12 Pro Max in debug mode...
Running pod install...                                              7.4s
Running Xcode build...                                                  
Xcode build done.                                           71.3s
Failed to build iOS app
Error output from Xcode build:
↳
    ** BUILD FAILED **


Xcode's output:
↳

    Command PhaseScriptExecution failed with a nonzero exit code
    note: Using new build system
    note: Building targets in parallel
    note: Planning build
    note: Constructing build description
    warning: Capabilities for Signing & Capabilities may not function correctly because its entitlements use a placeholder team ID. To resolve this, select a
    development team in the Runner editor. (in target 'Runner' from project 'Runner')

Could not build the application for the simulator.
Error launching application on iPhone 12 Pro Max.
```

Flutter doctor:

```
elamparithibalakrishnan@Elamparithis-MacBook-Pro ios % flutter doctor -v
[✓] Flutter (Channel master, 2.1.0-11.0.pre.229, on macOS 11.2 20D64 darwin-x64, locale en-GB)
    • Flutter version 2.1.0-11.0.pre.229 at /Users/elamparithibalakrishnan/Desktop/flutter
    • Framework revision d20ec4c7d8 (5 hours ago), 2021-03-11 22:18:51 -0800
    • Engine revision 1b68503bc8
    • Dart version 2.13.0 (build 2.13.0-125.0.dev)

[✓] Android toolchain - develop for Android devices (Android SDK version 30.0.3)
    • Android SDK at /Users/elamparithibalakrishnan/Library/Android/sdk
    • Platform android-30, build-tools 30.0.3
    • Java binary at: /Applications/Android Studio.app/Contents/jre/jdk/Contents/Home/bin/java
    • Java version OpenJDK Runtime Environment (build 1.8.0_242-release-1644-b3-6915495)
    • All Android licenses accepted.

[✓] Xcode - develop for iOS and macOS
    • Xcode at /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer
    • Xcode 12.4, Build version 12D4e
    • CocoaPods version 1.10.1

[✓] Chrome - develop for the web
    • Chrome at /Applications/Google Chrome.app/Contents/MacOS/Google Chrome

[✓] Android Studio (version 4.1)
    • Android Studio at /Applications/Android Studio.app/Contents
    • Flutter plugin can be installed from:
       https://plugins.jetbrains.com/plugin/9212-flutter
    • Dart plugin can be installed from:
       https://plugins.jetbrains.com/plugin/6351-dart
    • Java version OpenJDK Runtime Environment (build 1.8.0_242-release-1644-b3-6915495)

[✓] Connected device (3 available)
    • AOSP on IA Emulator (mobile) • emulator-5554                        • android-x86    • Android 9 (API 28) (emulator)
    • iPhone 12 Pro Max (mobile)   • 1E0E6387-F349-4ECA-9858-385698232158 • ios            • com.apple.CoreSimulator.SimRuntime.iOS-14-4 (simulator)
    • Chrome (web)                 • chrome                               • web-javascript • Google Chrome 89.0.4389.82

• No issues found!
```

I couldn't able to find the exact issue.

Can anyone please help me with this issue?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
warning: Capabilities for Signing & Capabilities may not function correctly because its entitlements use a placeholder team ID. To resolve this, select a
    development team in the Runner editor. (in target 'Runner' from project 'Runner')
```

You have to select a development team id in your xcode worspace file an rerun it after that.

Comment: Thanks for the response I have added the Team info in signing now the warning message is gone but still I can't able to run the app. Below is the output after adding the development team id.

`Xcode's output:
↳

    Command PhaseScriptExecution failed with a nonzero exit code
    note: Using new build system
    note: Building targets in parallel
    note: Planning build
    note: Constructing build description

Could not build the application for the simulator.
Error launching application on iPhone 12 Pro Max.`